# How do I resolve no work about setOnPlaceSelectedListener?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I want to create direction of two point using Google Map.
If source point is set, I want to see aaaaabbbbb message in Logcat.
But I can't see it.

Could someone tell me, please?

```
    // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment
    val autoCompleteFragment_s = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment_source) as AutocompleteSupportFragment
    val autoCompleteFragment_d = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment_destination) as AutocompleteSupportFragment

    // Specify the types of place data to return
    autoCompleteFragment_s.setPlaceFields(mutableListOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME))
    autoCompleteFragment_d.setPlaceFields(mutableListOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME))


    Log.i(javaClass.simpleName,"aaaaa")
    // Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
    autoCompleteFragment_s.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object: PlaceSelectionListener {

        override fun onPlaceSelected(place: Place){

            Log.i(javaClass.simpleName, "aaaaabbbbb")
            Log.i(javaClass.simpleName, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId())
            val latLngDest = LatLng(10.311794, 123.915863)
            googleMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(latLngDest).title("Ehime City"))

        }

        override fun onError(status: Status) {
            Log.i(javaClass.simpleName, "aaaaabbbbb")
            Log.i(javaClass.simpleName, "An error occurred: " + status)
        }
    })
```

Comment: do you see "Place: " in logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method to zoom map to that location :

```
public void animateMapCamera(LatLng point, int zoom) {
    if (googleMap != null) {
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point, zoom);
        googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
    }
}



    override fun onPlaceSelected(place: Place){

        Log.i(javaClass.simpleName, "aaaaabbbbb")
        Log.i(javaClass.simpleName, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId())
        val latLngDest = LatLng(10.311794, 123.915863)
        googleMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(latLngDest).title("Ehime City"))


            animateMapCamera(latLngDest, 17);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you your comment !
I couldn't see "aaaaabbbbb" message in Logcat, but I could see work of setOnPlaceSelectedListener by moving camera.

*I changed your code from Java to Kotlin.